# How to find hook running after last line of code?

Tags: org-mode, hooks, help

I have a repeating habit such as:

```
** TODO some habit
SCHEDULED: <2020-05-22 Fri 08:00 .+1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:CREATED:  [2020-05-08 Fri]
:LAST_REPEAT: [2020-05-21 Thu 10:07]
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-05-21 Thu 10:07]
CLOCK: [2020-05-21 Thu 10:04]--[2020-05-21 Thu 10:06] =>  0:02
:END:
```

I coded this shortcut, where I commented out my function to clock in and out:

```lisp
(defun my-org-clock-and-mark-done ()
  (interactive)
  (message "start")
  (org-back-to-heading)
  ;(my-org-clock-in-and-out nil)
  (org-shiftright)
  (message "end")
  )
```

The result in the `*Messages` buffer is:

```
start
Entry repeats: SCHEDULED: <2020-05-22 Fri 08:00 .+1d> 
end
Note stored
Entry repeats: SCHEDULED: <2020-05-22 Fri 08:00 .+1d>
```

I suspect that Org mode has a hook that runs after my last line of code, in this case when a repeating cookie is changed, and shows that change message twice.

How can I find and disable that hook?

**Update**: Following the answer by phils, I added a debugger with `(setq debug-on-message "Note stored")` so it catches only the second occurrence. It shows these functions, neither of which I could find in the list of hooks, which I found thanks to Muihlinn's comment. The list of calls is below and has two recursive edits, which I find odd:

```
  org-store-log-note()
  org-add-log-note()
  recursive-edit()
  debug(error ...)
  message("%s" #("Entry repeats: SCHEDULED: ..."))
  org-store-log-note()
  org-add-log-note()
  recursive-edit()
  debug(error #("Entry repeats: SCHEDULED: ..."))
  message("%s" #("Entry repeats: SCHEDULED: ..."))
  org-auto-repeat-maybe("DONE")
  org-todo(right)
  funcall-interactively(org-todo right)
  call-interactively(org-todo)
  org-shiftright()
```

Comment: have you checked `org-shiftright-hook`?

Comment: `M-x apropos-variable org hook` describes Org's hooks.

Comment: @Muihlinn `org-shiftright-hook` has value of `nil`. Besides, the extra lines appear after an additional line after `org-shift-right`.

Comment: @Drew I belive it's `M-x apropos-variable RET org hook`, and it's very informative, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case...

In that call to `org-auto-repeat-maybe` we see this:

```el
(when org-log-repeat
  (if (or (memq 'org-add-log-note (default-value 'post-command-hook))
          (memq 'org-add-log-note post-command-hook))
      ;; We are already setup for some record.
      (when (eq org-log-repeat 'note)
        ;; Make sure we take a note, not only a time stamp.
        (setq org-log-note-how 'note))
    ;; Set up for taking a record.
    (org-add-log-setup 'state
                       (or done-word (car org-done-keywords))
                       org-last-state
                       org-log-repeat)))
```

Where `org-log-repeat` is a user option (see which).

`org-add-log-setup` does this:

```el
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'org-add-log-note 'append))
```

And `org-add-log-note` removes itself from the hook when it runs:

```el
(defun org-add-log-note (&optional _purpose)
  "Pop up a window for taking a note, and add this note later."
  (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'org-add-log-note)
  ...)
```

So if `org-log-repeat` is non-nil, `post-command-hook` will be running `org-add-log-note`.

Comment: This removes the second notification (with `Note stored` and `Entry repeats...`) and also the state change from being logged in the logbook drawer. Can the first happend without the second?

Comment: I honestly don't know what any of this stuff is for, so I'm not in a position to recommend any changes.  I'm just pointing you to the mechanisms behind it.

Comment: I fixed the problem with code similar to the mechanism: add another `post-command-hook` after calling `org-shiftright`, then removing it from the called function. This way, my code is the last to run and stays displayed in the mini-buffer.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq debug-on-message "Entry repeats: SCHEDULED")`

The stack traces should show you what is causing each instance of that message.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Using Debugger` for help on the debugger.

When you're done, <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq debug-on-message nil)`

Comment: I updated the question after running this debugger.